# When to create new epoch for a Debian package?

Tags: debian, package-management, packaging, version

I undestand that `epoch` was created to ensure ordering when upstream changed version numbering scheme, but it seems redundant at first sight (we have enough version numbers already).

Let's take hypothetical example, `foo` version changing from `2016-12-24` to `1.0`.

Can the new package `foo-1.0` `replace` `foo:2016-12-25` instead of `foo` defining a new `epoch`?

Answer (score 3):

> Can the new package `foo-1.0` replace [...]

Sure, but then `foo-1.0` is a completely new and different package, not a new version of the `foo` package. The system won't consider them the same and won't offer `foo-1.0` as an upgrade path for `foo`. The `foo-1.0` package won't satisfy other packages that want to depend on `foo`.

Debian defined an epoch at the beginning of the version number for exactly the kind of case you describe. Version `1.0` is newer than version `2016-12-24` but it looks like it's older because 1 < 2016. So when this kind of renumbering happens upstream, you bump up the epoch. It's still the same package.

Comment: `Replaces` and `Provides` semantics should provide `foo` dependency to other packages. I guess that ensuring that only one package may provide upgrade path for `foo` explains using epoch as version component. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Honestly I wasn't thinking of `Replaces` and I suppose you could probably hack around the lack of an epoch with that if there was no such thing as the epoch, but you'd still be stuck carrying a new ugly name for the package, essentially forever.

Comment: @sevo Older versions of apt did not support `Replaces:` or versioned `Provides:`. Even today, I don't think the transition between packages with a different names is always as smooth as simply upgrading a package.