# What does the first colon-separated number in a Debian/APT package version number like 1:2.10.1-4 mean?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg

Let's take a look at the `amavisd-new` package:

```
# apt-cache policy amavisd-new
amavisd-new:
  Installed: 1:2.10.1-4
  Candidate: 1:2.10.1-4
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.10.1-4 500
 ...
```

The command returns `1:2.10.1-4` as though the actual `amavisd-new` version is `2.10.1-4`. What does the proceeding `1:` mean in front of the actual version number?

Comment: This is a less general rehash of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114708/5132 .  Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114708/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332617/5132 .

Answer (score 3):

From `man deb-version`:

> epoch
>
> This is a single (generally small) unsigned integer.  It may be omitted, in which case zero is assumed.  If it is omitted then the upstream-version may not contain any colons. It is provided to allow mistakes in the version numbers of older versions of a package, and also a package's previous version numbering schemes, to be left behind.